# Using minted to highlight single word

Tags: minted

for example, if I want to write:

```
\usepackage{minted}
```

My parents gave me some money.
I walked in the shop and `found some sweets` that I liked. I decided to buy them.

*In the above text how do I used minted package to highlight like the above*

Comment: Isn't \texttt{found some sweets} enough? Why do you want to use `minted`?

Comment: @CarLaTeX to get the nice grey background

Comment: There is `soul` package for that, as in leandris's answer.

Comment: Do you actually absolutely need to use minted for a specific reason or was your question about the font shape change and the highlighting? Because then tags and title should be adapted to reflect that.

Comment: hi @thymaro yes. I thought my tag and title was clear enough - do you have a suggested edit?

Comment: @piccolo no, it's clear enough. It's just that minted is completely overkill for this specific task. (Which is also the reason for which the provided answer doesn't use minted.)

Comment: @piccolo also, I think more context is needed to answer the question. It might depend on how you have set up minted in your preamble. An MWE would help getting a quality answer.

Comment: @thymaro okay. In that case I will accept the suggested solution using the other package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are also interested in the light gray background, you might find one of the two following methods useful:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor} % For the first and second example
\definecolor{mylightgray}{RGB}{239,240,241}
\usepackage{soul} % For the second example
\sethlcolor{mylightgray}

\begin{document}
My parents gave me some money. I walked in the shop and \colorbox{mylightgray}{\texttt{found some sweets}} that I liked. I decided to buy them.

My parents gave me some money. I walked in the shop and \hl{\texttt{found some sweets}} that I liked. I decided to buy them.
\end{document}
```

Please note that the first example will not allow line breaks inside of the gray box.